# datepicker Boostrap

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Estoy empezando a utilizar el `Datepicker` de `Bootstrap` porque necesito capturar 2 fechas para hacer una consulta de horas trabajadas, mi problema es que me genera este error:

> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (dashboard.js:12)
>       at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
>       at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)

No se el porqué, ya tengo instaladas las librerías de `Bootstrap` y `jQuery` no se que me haga falta.

Este es mi codigo HTML:

```
<div class="datepick container">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <label>Desde:</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="gyphicon gyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <label>Hasta:</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" />
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="gyphicon gyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y este el JavaScript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false,
        format: 'YY.MM.DD'
    });
    $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

Comment: Pon aquí tu código para que podamos verlo y saber por qué ocurre el error. Sin ver el código lo único que podemos decirte es lo mismo que indica el error.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stackoverflow en español, es importante que leas [ask] para que sepas como formular preguntas que sean bien recibidas en la comunidad, debes mostrarnos el código que estás implementando para poderte ayudar, saludos!

Comment: Parece que no tienes agregada la [biblioteca de datepicker](https://code.jquery.com/ui/).

Comment: necesitamos ver codigo, pero fijate que la ref a jquery.js esté primero que la del datetime.js

Comment: Parece que es lo que dice A. Cedano o puede que estés cargando la biblioteca antes que el jQuery en sí y entonces no se reconocen las funciones jQuery usadas. Revisa que estés cargando el jQuery antes de cualquier otra biblioteca. Sería bueno que pusieras el código donde usas el datepicker y también donde haces las llamadas a las bibliotecas. Saludos.